# How to use split to split with commas except the comma that has one preceding character and 6 succeeding characters

Tags: javascript

So I have a string like this transaction_20,190.68,huwaei,2019/02/14,1,256.32,AUS

I want the string to be split after comma but i dont want to split this comma 1,256.32 as this is the price and I noticed that the comma I dont want to split always have 1 preceding character and 6 succeeding characters. Can somebody please help me out in order to how to do this in javascript. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When splitting on a comma, negative lookahead for 3 digits followed by a word boundary:

```js
const input = 'transaction_20,190.68,huwaei,2019/02/14,1,256.32,AUS';
const splitted = input.split(/,(?!\d{3}\b)/);
console.log(splitted);
```